# memcached doesn't expire on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, memcached

I am using memcached on my codeigniter project. I want to expire it after 1 hour but it doesn't work. My code is -

```
$this->memcached_library->set('users',0,60*60);
```

Thanks in advance.